# Expire previous versions of a static web page

Tags: html, caching, browser, header

I have a static web page on Dropbox, served via http://updog.co/ , which I create with a build script.  The script sets the `EXPIRES` header like so:

```
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES"       CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2017 11:12:01 GMT">
```

The problem with this is that when I update the page with some new content, my browser (on my phone, at least), doesn't notice that the page has changed, and gives me the old one.

Is there a way that I can get it so that whenever I build a new version, I can set some header which tells it to not use the old one?